# An unbiased estimator for the parameter of exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

The times between arrivals at a fish shop queue can be described by an exponential distribution $X$ with parameter $\theta$ .

If $Y$ is the random variable given by the sample mean on **$n$** inter-arrival times

Write down an expression for an unbiased estimator $T$ of $\theta$.

---

The answer is:

**$T=\frac{1}{Y}(1-\frac{1}{n})$**

However when I tested if it is unbiased I found $E(T)$ is $(n-1)θ$ instead of $θ$

What I have done is:
Finding  $E(\frac{1}{Y}) = nθ$, to make it $= θ$, I divide it by n,
So I can set $T = \frac{1}{nY}$

In my view,  from the given answer, $E(\frac{1}{Y})$ is supposed to be $[\dfrac{n}{n-1}]θ$, in order to make E(T) = θ, but I can't get it...

I don't know where the **$(n-1)$** comes from.

Here is my working:

Since Y is the sample mean of n arrivals

$$E(Y) = n\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i = \frac{1}{n\theta}$$
therefore
$$E(\frac{1}{Y})= n\theta$$

Comment: i have edited the question, pls check that thx @user91500

Comment: "Finding E(1/Y)=nθ" should make an alarm ring since, by the LLN, 1/Y is approximately θ when n is large.

Comment: @Did so do u know where the $(n-1)$ comes from?

Comment: Yes, and we could help you see it too if only you showed the computations that led you to the (erroneous) identity E(1/Y)=nθ.

Comment: I have edited it pls check that thx :) @Did

Comment: The step [E(Y)=something "therefore" E(1/Y)=1/something] is false (interestingly it is *always* false except for constant random variables).

Comment: Do you mean $E(\frac{1}{X})=\frac{1}{E(X)}$ is not necessarily true?

Comment: Tell me... (But apparently you are not interested anymore since you just "accepted" an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naively, you would think that the rate parameter would be estimated by the reciprocal of the average time to wait. So you start with the estimator $\frac{1}{Y}$. Then you calculate its expected value. You will find that it is not $\theta$, but is proportional to $\theta$. Then divide the proportionality constant out to make an unbiased estimator.

If you need more help, you might look into the derivation of the usual unbiased estimator for the variance, namely $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left (  x_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right )^2$. Basically this goes by considering $S_1^2$ which has an $n$ instead of $n-1$, calculating $E[S_1^2]=\frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2$, and then correcting it.

Comment: however when i tested the answer if it is biassed, i found that $E(T)=(n-1)\theta $. Im wondering where I have made a mistake. The expected of $1/Y$ is $n\theta$, isn't it?  @Ian

Comment: @Alan I didn't try it, but apparently (from the solution you were given) you should have $E[1/Y]=\frac{n}{n-1} \theta$.